# How to make copy and paste run faster on google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My code is timing out and not finishing. It is just a copy and paste code pretty much. The part that is failling is when it copies to the week days tabs. I am not sure if there is something wrong or if there is another way I could make it faster. Please guidance?

```
function myFunction() {
 var week=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Production Overview').getRange('b1').getValue();
 var pasteweek= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Production Overview').getRange('b1').setValue(week);
 var weekdays= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Production Overview').getRange('c3:i3').getDisplayValues();
 var pasteweekdays= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Production Overview').getRange('c3:i3').setValues(weekdays);

var rosterclearup=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange(1,1,1000,13)
rosterclearup.clearContent()
var yushoroster=sheet =SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ILFN5xehSjnRbCWPq20ZJBZF678K6mgn-FerNWv6gCo").getSheetByName('Attendance Sheet').getRange(1,1,1000,13).getDisplayValues()
var pasteroster=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange(1,1,1000,13).setValues(yushoroster)//
var sortingalphabetically=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange('A2:M').sort({column: 2, ascending: true,header: true})


let lastrowAM=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange('P1:P').getLastRow()
let lastrowPM=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange('O1:O').getLastRow()

let copyAM= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange(2,16,lastrowAM,).getDisplayValues()
let copyPM= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange(2,17,lastrowPM,).getDisplayValues()

let pasteAM= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Thursday').getRange(4,2,lastrowAM).setValues(copyAM)
let pastePM1= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Thursday').getRange(242,2,lastrowPM).setValues(copyPM)
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Thrusday Copied")

let pasteAM2= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Friday').getRange(4,2,lastrowAM).setValues(copyAM)
let pastePM2= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Friday').getRange(242,2,lastrowPM).setValues(copyPM)
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Friday Copied")

let pasteAM3= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Saturday').getRange(4,2,lastrowAM).setValues(copyAM)
let pastePM3= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Saturday').getRange(242,2,lastrowPM).setValues(copyPM)
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Saturday Copied")

let pasteAM4= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sunday').getRange(4,2,lastrowAM).setValues(copyAM) 
let pastePM4= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sunday').getRange(242,2,lastrowPM).setValues(copyPM)
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Sunday Copied")

let pasteAM5= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Monday').getRange(4,2,lastrowAM).setValues(copyAM)
let pastePM5= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Monday').getRange(242,2,lastrowPM).setValues(copyPM)
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Monday Copied")

let pasteAM6= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Tuesday').getRange(4,2,lastrowAM).setValues(copyAM)
let pastePM6= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Tuesday').getRange(242,2,lastrowPM).setValues(copyPM)
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Tuesday Copied")


let pasteAM7= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Wednesday').getRange(4,2,lastrowAM).setValues(copyAM)
let pastePM7= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Wednesday').getRange(242,2,lastrowPM).setValues(copyPM)
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Wednesday Copied")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script you make a lot of redundant calls to SpreadsheetApp.  You only need to do it once and retain a reference to that Active spreadsheet.

You all so use ambiguous ranges such as ("P1:P").  This can result in a lot of empty cells being retrieved.  You only need to call `.getLastRow()` of the sheet to get the actual number of rows with data.  Also since you are getting data starting from row 2 you need to subtract 1 from the get last row results.

Here is how I would clean up your script.

```
function myFunction() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Production Overview");

  // you get the value(s) and put it right back
  // why? var week=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Production Overview').getRange('b1').getValue();
  // why? var pasteweek= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Production Overview').getRange('b1').setValue(week);
  // why? var weekdays= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Production Overview').getRange('c3:i3').getDisplayValues();
  // why? var pasteweekdays= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Production Overview').getRange('c3:i3').setValues(weekdays);

  // I'm assuming you used (1,1,1000,13) to insure you got all the data and nothing is beyond row 1000
  let rosterclearup=spread.getSheetByName('Roster').getDataRange();
  rosterclearup.clearContent();

  let yushoroster = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ILFN5xehSjnRbCWPq20ZJBZF678K6mgn-FerNWv6gCo").getSheetByName('Attendance Sheet').getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Roster");
  sheet.getRange(1,1,yushoroster.length,yushoroster[0].length).setValues(yushoroster);
  sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,13).sort({column: 2, ascending: true,header: true});

  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()-1;  // since you get from row 2
  // these two will be the same value
  // let lastrowAM = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange('P1:P').getLastRow()
  // let lastrowPM = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster').getRange('O1:O').getLastRow()

  let copyAM = sheet.getRange(2,16,lastRow,1).getDisplayValues();
  let copyPM = sheet.getRange(2,17,lastRow,1).getDisplayValues();

  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Thursday");
  sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyAM);
  sheet.getRange(242,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyPM);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Thrusday Copied");

  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Friday");
  sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyAM);
  sheet.getRange(242,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyPM);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Friday Copied");

  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Saturday");
  sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyAM);
  sheet.getRange(242,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyPM);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Saturday Copied")

  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sunday");
  sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyAM);
  sheet.getRange(242,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyPM);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Sunday Copied")

  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Monday");
  sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyAM);
  sheet.getRange(242,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyPM);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Monday Copied")

  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Tuesday");
  sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyAM);
  sheet.getRange(242,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyPM);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Tuesday Copied")

  sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Wednesday");
  sheet.getRange(4,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyAM);
  sheet.getRange(242,2,lastRow,1).setValues(copyPM);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Wednesday Copied")
}
```